# How to keep Folder/Files of extension in the uninstall process

Tags: plugins, joomla, module, components, joomla3.0

I want to keep the all the file structure of extension when we uninstall any extension from the site.

In the uninstall process I want to remove DB tables only and want to keep all Files/Folders.

Can you please guide me if there is any solution.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked and we can disable the the File & Folder removing code from library : /libraries/cms/installer/adapter

but I'm looking for solution without customizing Joomla Library code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manifest file](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) for the extension includes a list of the relevant files that are installed for the extension. These can be copied from the website and zipped to recreate the install file for the extension.

Some extensions may also create associated data which you can back up by exporting relevant database tables and/or files (e.g. in the media or images folders).

Answer (score 0):

A normal uninstall process (via Joomla! manage form) removes everything unless the extension has bug in its uninstall schedule. So, if you need to keep the files, uninstalling the extension won't be a good idea. I suggest you drop tables via phpMyAdmin instead.
To do that, go to your web hosting control panel (cPanel, DirectAdmin etc.) and look for the link to phpMyAdmin. Then select the database that contains your website data (if you got multiple databases and are not sure which one is the right one, you can check it via Joomla! admin > Global Configuration). When you found the database in phpMyAdmin, click on its name to go to its tables. Then select the table(s) of that specific extension by checking the checkbox(es) beside them. Then at the bottom of the all tables click "Drop". In the popup window click "OK" and the table(s) will be removed without effecting your folders/files.

I suggest you get a backup of your whole website first, if you're new to phpMyAdmin.

Be careful!

Comment: @Arashted Ltd

I have checked and we can disable the the File & Folder removing code from library : /libraries/cms/installer/adapter
but I'm looking for solution without customizing Joomla Library code.